# ListView with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

i have a listview with 3 text. NV1 - NV2 - NV3. My problem is when I touch on NV1 the intent show me the layout of NV1. But with the others nothing happen. It just show me the same NV.

I create a 2 method for passing the info.

```
    private void adapter (PT1Activity a){
      this.a = a;
  }

private void showGame(int nivel){
    Intent intent = new Intent (PT1Activity.this, NV1.class);
    intent.putExtra("nivel2", nivel);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And a:

private PT1Activity a;

adapter(this);

```
       ltNvs.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {


             a.showGame(position);
        }
    });
```

**What I have to do? Pass the information to the other NV2 Activity with a Bundle?? Or something similar?**

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. According to your code, all three buttons in your listview should call showGame, which always starts NV1.class. Did you want to launch a different .class file depending on which button is pressed?

Comment: Exactly but I don´t think that I have to create new 2 method for the other .class

Comment: You don't need to add new methods, but you need to have some sort of switch/if statements to determine what position has been clicked on. It won't just magically know.

Comment: Your showGame() method directly calls NV1, how can you expect it to open NV2? or NV3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your showgame function should be something like this:

```
private void showGame(int nivel){
Intent intent;
switch (nivel){
    case 1:
      intent = new Intent (PT1Activity.this, NV1.class);
      intent.putExtra("nivel1", nivel);
      break;
    case 2:
      intent = new Intent (PT1Activity.this, NV2.class);
      intent.putExtra("nivel2", nivel);
      break;
    case 3:
      intent = new Intent (PT1Activity.this, NV3.class);
      intent.putExtra("nivel3", nivel);
      break;
    default:
      intent = new Intent();
   }

startActivity(intent);
}
```

However, this assumes all your classes are in the same package. If you want to launch an activity in a different package, the `Intent(this, yourclass.Class)` constructor won't work. Instead, try something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("your.other.package/your.other.package.your_other_class_name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Note: your_other_class_name would be something like `NV1`, not `NV1.class`.

Comment: Sorry, had invalid syntax on the default case. Should be fixed now... assuming you have all the correct things available (three classes named NV1, NV2, NV3)

Comment: I have an error. "ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent"

Comment: Do you have four activities named PT1Activity, NV1, NV2, and NV3?

Comment: Yes ubt in two different packages

Comment: Edited my answer to address launching things outside your package.

Answer (score 0):

I have to be honest, I'm not completely sure what it is you're asking for. Hopefully looking at this you can get an idea.

```
private void showGame(int nivel){
    switch( nivel ) {
    case 1:
        Intent intent = new Intent (PT1Activity.this, NV1.class);
        intent.putExtra("nivel1", nivel);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 2:
        Intent intent = new Intent( PT1Activity.this, NV2.class );
        intent.putExtra( "nivel2", nivel );
        startActivity( intent );
        break;
    case 3:
        Intent intent = new Intent( PT1Activity.this, NV3.class );
        intent.putExtra( "nivel3", nivel );
        startActivity( intent );
        break;
}
```

Comment: I tryed to do with your code JuiCe. But I have an "ActivityNotFoundExeption". The weird is that I declare in the .manifest

Comment: Did you try matt's code above? I was just trying to give you the gist of it.

Comment: Have you written the NV2 and NV3 activities?

Comment: Yes I re-write the code of JuiCe. But I have this error:"ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent" or "ActivityNotFoundException: and it said that i didn't declare another class but i already did